# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Customers' because no a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to send a enumerable customer object in ViewResult to Index view of customers. but i am not able to use foreach with Model on the view page.
The error associated with model says -

"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Customers' because 'Customers' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

i tried to switch the code with an array but the problem remains

```
public class Customers
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


    }

//Customer Controller
public class CustomersController : Controller
    {

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var customers = GetCustomers();
            return View(customers));
        }

        public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var customer = GetCustomers().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            return View(customer);

        }

         private IEnumerable<Customers> GetCustomers()
         {
             var customer =  new List<Customers>
             {
                 new Customers { Id = 1, Name = "John Smith"},
                 new Customers { Id = 2, Name = "Mary Williams"}
             };

            return customer;
         }


    }

//View page Index

 @foreach (var customer in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Customers" asp-action="Details">@customer.Name</a></td>
            </tr>
        }
```

[The error displayed Under Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpGIE.png)
when the foreach statements executes, the it should output the name of the customers accordingly

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` does not result in a collection, it is a single `Customers`. Use `Where` instead if you want a collection, even if there is only one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view you describe model as single object `Customer`.

Change your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Model.Customer>
```

Or:

```
@model List<Vidly.Model.Customer>
```

Comment: Thanks..That worked!... but a new internal error now says:
 The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[Vidly.Models.Customers]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Vidly.Models.Customers]'.

Comment: @WesMes change to `List`

Comment: i changed it to List..
But the error persists says:
ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Vidly.Models.Customers]'